# How can you properly execute asynchronous code before you use Navigator in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to execute a function before I navigate using Navigator. Only issue is I get an error saying "Function expressions cannot be named" on my function when I try to call it before I navigate onTap. What exactly am I doing wrong and what is the proper way to do this? This is what I have currently.

```
          ListTile(
          title: Text("Logout"),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
          onTap: () async => await UserDBProvider.userDB.deleteUser() {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage())
            );
          }
          
      ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```dart
      onTap: () async {
          await UserDBProvider.userDB.deleteUser();
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
            ),
          );
        },
```